# Am looking for a way to show random products in products category page using woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I change product in same category randomly? I've been looking but can't seem to find any plugin/script to do this, anyone got an idea on this... thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please check my answer, This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to display the products rows of "*CATXXX*" :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[product_category category="CATXXX" per_page="8" columns="4" orderby="rand"]' ) ?>
```

Also you can treat products like any other post type and query using [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Limit the number of posts retrieved to 1 and change the *orderby* parameter to random:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'orderby'          => 'rand',
    'category'         => 'CATXXX'
    'post_type'        => 'product'); 

$random_products = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You can also use new [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) which would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code shortcode

```
[product_category category="category_slug" per_page="10" orderby="rand"]

Or

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[product_category category="category_slug" per_page="10" orderby="rand"]' ) ?>
```